# Why does adding the value 2 to the si only increment the index by 1?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm a beginner to the x86 architecture and assembly, this is a code snippet with the steps through below it.

I know that the si is the source index and it acts as the index to the array.

The highlighted line indicates that 2 is being added to it, however the answer suggests that we only move up an index of 1.

I'm sure I'm interpreting it wrong, if someone can explain what is happening that would help a lot!

Assembly newbie-friendly vocab preferred!

[image]

Comment: the `word ptr[si]` doesn't act like a _C_ array. `si` will be the address used as the memory operand at which a word (16-bit) value will be read. If you add 2 to _SI_ that increments the pointer by 2 which is a single word (16-bit value).

Comment: How many bytes is a 16bit word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs because the data in **array** is being treated as a different type as the indexing in **si**.

Since `array` is declared with `dw` (data words, 16 bit elements) and `si` is a pointer which indexes memory on a byte basis (8 bits), `si` must take two "steps" for each word index you wish to traverse. Otherwise, you'd end up alternating between the high-order and low-order bytes of each word in the array.

In computer-science terminology, x86 is *byte addressable*, and your array elements are multi-byte.

Comment: words are 16, dword 32 and qword 64 bits

Comment: @MichaelPetch isn't that version dependent? You may be right but I believe it varies.

Comment: In x86 **assembly** they are always the same. In a higher level language they may vary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: Per Wikipedia (of course) the x86 word size has twice been extended, from 16 to 32 to 64 bits. But I think this is a semantic difference between *word* meaning the size of the chunks the processor natively handles data in versus *word* meaning the size of the data type declared by the keyword. I think I mixed them up; I saw *word* and thought of the bus size.

Comment: Likely you are confusing an actual machine word and the definition in x86 assembly when it comes to type specification. The x86 Intel syntax always  has the same definitions for type specification. Byte/8, Word/16, Dword/32, Qword/64, Tword/80 which map to the operand sizes on the x86 processor.

Comment: "I think I mixed them up; I saw word and thought of the bus size." Yes, that is what I meant. Gone are the good old days when *word* and *word* meant the same thing. Apologies if I came across as rude.

Comment: `dw` is "data -- words", not double words, and x86 defines words as 2 bytes/16 bits.  `dd` is for double words, which are 32 bits.

Comment: could you correct the answer to "dw (data word - 16 bits)" and "Si indexing on byte basis" please?

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.